# Change page title output

Tags: theming, 8

How can I change the page title output?

```
<title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```

in html.html.twig changes the mark/letter which creates: `<pagetitle> | <sitename>`, but I want to change this order to `<sitename> | <pagetitle>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option without the extra module overhead (still a valid option):

```
<title>{{ head_title|reverse|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```

Simply add the [reverse](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/reverse.html) filter to that part of your html.html.twig file

Twig rulez! Cheers!

Comment: I have accepted your answer, because more "simpler" way, and does exactly what I wanted. However, I wen't with the metatag module. I looked at it, and it seems to be interesting module to play with anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using the [Meta Tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module

[image]

Click on override and switch it.